# Delete an (unmerged) Git branch when it is no longer active?

Tags: git, branch, git-tag

I have some maintenance branches in Git that were used to create emergency releases (i.e. to fix a critical bug in production). These branches are usually not merged back to master, because they either contain one-off fixes or have changes that were cherry-picked from master.

As a matter of practice, should these maintenance branches be deleted in Git if they are tagged (at build time)? Will deleting them cause those commits to be lost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No commit will be lost if it's reachable from a tag or a branch head.

If you tagged a branch, and then made another commit, and then deleted the branch, that last commit would be liable to garbage collection (at some point in the future - you can still recover it using reflog if you don't wait too long).

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if it makes sense to always delete the branches for housekeeping purposes since the tip of each branch is tagged.

Comment: So long as the tip is tagged you won't lose anything, but I doubt this housekeeping really buys you anything either.

Comment: just to cut down on the number of branches in the repository. It's easier to see only the branches that are actively being developed instead of having a bunch of dead ones accumulating over time.